# Getting results from odbc/sql query into csv

Tags: php, sql, csv, odbc

I have a PHP script running that executes an odbc sql query and I'm trying to write those results to a CSV.

The script runs with no more errors, as I fixed a few issues with my loops already. However, the CSV (even though it shows it was edited at the time the script is run) only has the headers written to it, but no results are being written to it whatsoever.

Without any error messages, I'm thinking maybe it's just not catching or writing the results correctly even though it's not getting a particular error.

Here's the bulk of the script, query omitted as it's rather long

```
try {
                $DB2Conn = odbc_connect(/*credentials omitted*/);

                $plcQueryDB2 = " /*Long query omitted*/ ";

                $prep = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);
                $exec = odbc_execute($prep);

            }
            catch(Exception $e) {  
                echo $e->getMessage();  
            } 

            $result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $plcQueryDB2);

            // Writing column headers
            $columns = array('rep', 'Dealer', 'Style', 'StyleName', 'Frame', 'Cover', 'Color', 'Colorname', 'Placements', 'shipdate');
            $fs = fopen('DB2_Query.csv', 'w');
            fputcsv($fs, $columns);      
            fclose($fs);

            // Writing data rows
            while(odbc_fetch_array($result)){
              for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_rows($result);$i++){ 
                $fs = fopen('DB2_Query.csv', 'a');
                  fputcsv($fs, odbc_result($result,$i));
                fclose($fs);
              }
            }

            echo $columns;

            odbc_close($DB2Conn);
            $DB2Conn = null;
```

Comment: First quick check to make - the SQL query does return data?

Comment: Yes, I started with just that but it does return several thousand records successfully